# How system is calculating to get the NumberOfLogicalProcessors in VB

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2008

For a **Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU  Q8400  @ 2.66GHz** model cpu I am getting both the **NumberOfCores** and **NumberOfLogicalProcessors** as 4 .

I want to know how system is calculating **NumberOfLogicalProcessors** ?

What i should use to get the actual number of cpus ?

OS: win2k8 R2

Comment: I assume you're using a WMI query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you meant by *actual CPU*.

`Win32_Processor\NumberOfCores` specifies the total number of *physical* CPU cores. A chip can contain one or more CPU cores.

`Win32_Processor\NumberOfLogicalProcessors` specifies the total number of *virtual* CPU cores. There can be two or more *virtual* CPU cores in one *physical* CPU core. On x86 compatible computers, this is only available in Intel's [Hyper-Threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) capable CPUs.

On the other hand, the `Win32_ComputerSystem\NumberOfProcessors` specifies the total number of *physical* processor chips installed on a multi processor motherboard.

The `Win32_ComputerSystem\NumberOfLogicalProcessors` is same as `Win32_Processor\NumberOfLogicalProcessors`.